# Remove all instances of a character from a column within tag

Tags: replace

I don't know much about writing SQL and a client of mine has an erroneous semicolon appearing in his database that he'd like removed. It's in 1 specific column, but it should only be removed if it is within an  tag. For example:

```
MyColumn
--------
<div style="this;is;ok;">This is okay; but <img src="this;"/> is not</div>
```

Can this be done?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Just get all rows containing the `;` and process them in some programming language where you have a html-parsing library available. You just cannot do that properly with some regular expressions and writing the parser in SQL is not going to be worth it.

Comment: jkavalik, so you're saying this can't be done directly in SQL Management Studio and I'll need to query the db in another language (I'm using C#) and then manage the results from there?

Comment: @Snailer It probably can be done, but the solution might be too convoluted.. From what you wrote it seems you need to parse the tags and understand them. It cannot be done with regex because HTML is not a regular language - it is context-free which is too "powerful" for regexp. But you can check if MSSQL maybe contains some ready-made functions for that (I am quite sure it can work with XML which is "the same level" so if your html is xhtml "compatible" you might even try to use them directly. Still it seems much easier to just run some quick C# (or other) script - tested by dry run at least.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - yes, it could be done

Correct and full answer depends from other information

For single (or predefined number of tags) - You can prepare UPDATE SQL for XML nodes and use REPLACE T-SQL function for updated parameters

The is will work if You need remove all ";" from TAG, if logic more complicated - solution will not work.